# Does a "no hunting" sign on its own imply other activities are okay?

Tags: united-states, oregon, trespassing

If a property has a "No Hunting" sign but not a "No Trespassing" sign, is it legal to go on that property for reasons other than hunting?

Comment: One of the canons of law is that the exclusion of one thing implies the inclusion of others, but that is more for interpretation of statutes than signs.

Comment: In the US, lae on this might vary from one state to another. Are you interested in any particular state?

Comment: @DavidSiegel yes, Oregon. I added the tag.